# Install docker and docker compose

Tags: release-odin

I use ubuntu repository for installing docker in elementory OS 6.
I think what it's would be use **focal**/ registry, but it return error - `E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu odin Release' does not have a Release file.`

How can I change it to **focal**?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and change docker.list from `deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu   odin stable` to `deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu   focal stable`